# Smooth custom paging for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I have two (possibly more) views in a UIScrollView and want to use paging with it. The problem arises when I try to use the default Paging option for UIScrollView, since the views have different widths it can not page properly.

So I have implemented a custom paging code which works. However, when the scrolls are slow, it does not function as expected. (It goes back to the original position without animation.)

Here is how I currently do the custom paging through the UIScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if direction == 1{
        targetContentOffset.pointee.x = 0
    }else{
        targetContentOffset.pointee.x = 100
    }
}
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).x > 0 {
        direction = 1
    }
    else {
        direction = 0
    }
}
```

What I want:
[image]
What I have:
[image]

Comment: Try to change your condition to `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).x >= 0`. It is possible that the scrollview is calling `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` even if the x delta is 0 so your direction will invert and probably mess with your logic.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about things you want to display there and maybe gif how it's behave? Because for my point of view this can be done with `UICollectionView`. But gif/screenshot may help with better understanding the problem

Comment: @valcanaia I just tried your solution, it unfortunately messed it up even more

Comment: @Kuba I have attached two gifs, ideal and the current app state.

Comment: You should definetly use `UICollectionView` required behaviour that you show is build in.

Answer (score 3):

try to below example for Custom UIScrollView Class

```
import UIKit

public class BaseScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    public var leftVc: UIViewController!
    public var middleVc: UIViewController!
    public var rightVc: UIViewController!

    public var initialContentOffset = CGPoint() // scrollView initial offset
    public var maximumWidthFirstView : CGFloat = 0

    public var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    public class func containerViewWith(_ leftVC: UIViewController,
                                        middleVC: UIViewController,
                                        rightVC: UIViewController) -> BaseScrollViewViewController {
        let container = BaseScrollViewViewController()

        container.leftVc = leftVC
        container.middleVc = middleVC
        container.rightVc = rightVC
        return container
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupHorizontalScrollView()
    }

    func setupHorizontalScrollView() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.bounces = false

        let view = (
            x: self.view.bounds.origin.x,
            y: self.view.bounds.origin.y,
            width: self.view.bounds.width,
            height: self.view.bounds.height
        )

        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: view.x,
                                  y: view.y,
                                  width: view.width,
                                  height: view.height
        )

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let scrollWidth  = 3 * view.width
        let scrollHeight  = view.height
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollWidth, height: scrollHeight)

        leftVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                   y: 0,
                                   width: view.width,
                                   height: view.height
        )

        middleVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: view.width,
                                               y: 0,
                                               width: view.width,
                                               height: view.height
        )

        rightVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 2 * view.width,
                                    y: 0,
                                    width: view.width,
                                    height: view.height
        )

        addChildViewController(leftVc)
        addChildViewController(middleVc)
        addChildViewController(rightVc)

        scrollView.addSubview(leftVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(middleVc.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(rightVc.view)

        leftVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        middleVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        rightVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        scrollView.contentOffset.x = middleVc.view.frame.origin.x
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }


    public func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.initialContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }

    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if maximumWidthFirstView != 0
        {
            if scrollView.contentOffset.x < maximumWidthFirstView
            {
                scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
                let newOffset = CGPoint(x: maximumWidthFirstView, y: self.initialContentOffset.y)

                self.scrollView!.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated:  false)
                scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Use of BaseScrollViewController**

```
let left = FirstController.init()
let middle = MiddleController()
let right = RightController.init()

let container = BaseScrollViewController.containerViewWith(left,middleVC: middle,rightVC: right)
container.maximumWidthFirstView = 150
```

**Output:**

[image: simulator screen shot 14-sep-2017 12 57 09 pm]  [image: simulator screen shot 14-sep-2017 12 57 05 pm]  [image: simulator screen shot 14-sep-2017 12 59 38 pm]

GitHub gist Example code: https://gist.github.com/mspvirajpatel/58dac2fae0d3b4077a0cb6122def6570

Comment: Can you please attach a gif showing the animation of the paging?

Answer (score 2):

I have previously written a short memo about this problem, and I'll copy/paste it since it is no longer accessible from anywhere. This may not be a specific answer and the codes are pretty old, but I hope this would help you in some degree.

---

If you have used a paging feature included in `UIScrollView`, you might also have tempted to customize the width of each page instead of a default, boring, frame width paging. It would be great if you can make the scroll stop at shorter or longer intervals than just multiples of its frame width. Surprisingly, there's no built-in way to configure the width of pages even in our latest iOS7 SDK. There are some ways to achieve custom paging, but none of them I would say are complete. As for now, you'll have to choose either of the following solutions.

**1. Change the frame size of your UIScrollView**

*Alexander Repty* has introduced a nice and easy solution to this problem and also included a sample code through his blog: http://blog.proculo.de/archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html

Basically, the instruction can be watered down to the following steps:

> 1. Create UIView subclass and override `hitTest: withEvent:`.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        if ([self.subviews count] == 0) return nil;
        else return [self.subviews lastObject];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

> 2. Include `UIScrollView` as a subview of the above `UIView` subclass.
> 3. Adjust the frame size of your `UIScrollView`.
> 4. Set `clipsToBound` property of your scroll view to `NO`.
> 5. Set `pagingEnabled` property of your scroll view to `YES`.

As you can see, I've just assumed that there is only one subview (the scrollView!) to your `UIView` subclass. Since you are passing all the touch events occurred in the `UIView` subclass to your `UIScrollView`, you'll be able to scroll the content by panning on the `UIView` subclass, but the paging width will be decided by the width of `UIScrollView`'s frame.

The best part of this approach is that you'll get the genuine feeling and responsiveness, as it is somewhat hard to mimic the paging by using `UIScrollView` delegate methods.

The only problem I found using this solution is that the width of all pages will have to be identical. You can't set different widths to different pages. If you tries to change your scrollView's frame size dynamically, you'll find there're a number of new emerging problems to deal with. Before trying to fix these glitches, you may want to check out other two solutions using `UIScrollView` delegates.

**2. scrollViewWillEndDragging: withVelocity: targetContentOffset**

`scrollViewWillEndDragging: withVelocity: targetContentOffset` is one of the latest `UIScrollView` delegate methods(iOS 5.0 or up) that gives you more information than the other old ones.

Since you get the velocity of the scrollView right after you lift the finger up from the screen, we can figure out the direction of the scrolled contents. The last argument, targetContentOffset, not only gives you the expected offset when the scrolling stops eventually, you can also assign CGPoint value in order to let the scrollView scrolls to the desired point.

```
targetContentOffset = CGPointMake(500, 0);
```

or

```
targetContentOffset->x = 500;
```

However, this will not work as you would think it should because you cannot set the speed of scrolling animation. It feels more like the scrollView happens to stop at the right point rather than it snaps to the spot. I also have to warn you that manually scrolling the contents with `setContentOffset: animated:` or just by using `UIView` animation inside the method will not work as expected.

If the velocity is 0, however, you may(and you have to) use manual scrolling to make it snap to the nearest paging point.

It could be the simplest and the most clean approach among all, but the major downside is that it does not provide the same experience that you always had with the real paging feature. To be more honest, it's not even similar to what we call paging. For the better result, we need to combine more delegate methods.

**3. Use multiple UIScrollView delegate methods**

From my shallow experience, an attempt to scroll your scrollView manually inside any `UIScrollView` delegate methods will only work when your scrollView has started to decelerate, or when it's not scrolling at all. Therefore, the best place I've found to perform the manual scrolling is `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:`.

Before looking inside the sample code, remember `scrollViewEndDragging: withVelocity: targetContentOffset:` method will always called prior to `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:`.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    _scrollVelocity = velocity.x;
    if (_scrollVelocity == 0) {
        // Find the nearest paging point and scroll.
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_scrollVelocity < 0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        scrollView.contentOffset = // Previous page offset
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    } else if (_scrollVelocity > 0) {
        // Animate to the next page offset
    }
}
```

`_scrollVelocity` is meant to be a global variable or a property, and I've assumed that you have your own ways to decide paging offsets for each page. Note that you'll have to handle the case of zero velocity inside the upper method because the latter method will not be called.

`UIView` animation with the duration 0.3 and the EaseOut curve option gave me the best result, but of course you should try other combinations to find what's the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This not the exact solution you might be looking for.

1) Check the offset of the scrollView when it reaches 0, You could show the VIEW you have above , You could animate while checking the scrollview movement so that it looks nice .But not completely

2) Now the VIEW is partially above your camera(you can decrease it alpha so that scrollview is still visible).

3) user can tap the view and you can show it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider calculating the most visible cell in your collection view after dragging ends and then programmatically scroll to – and center – that cell.

So something like:

First, implement the `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_:willDecelerate:)` method of your collection view's delegate. Then, in that method's body, determine which cell in `collectionView.visibleCells` is most visible by comparing each of their centers against your collection view's center. Once you find your collection view's most visible cell, scroll to it by calling `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)`.